# Multiple photo post replacement for publish_actions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

We are using server side to post users several photos into an album using the publish_actions. Unfortunately Facebook are shutting down this permission in august and encourage its user to migrate to share dialogs. The dialogs have 2 problems with posting multiple photos:
1 they are built for links (with OG:Tags in them) and not for photos.
2 they require several clicks for each post and will become a UX nightmare for posting an album of say 10 photos.

Anyone found a good replacement / solution?